# NSAttributedString freeze UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

Application really freeze while scrolling with NSAttributedString (When I use NSString it works fine), so there my method:

```
- (void)setSubtitleForCell:(TTTableViewCell *)cell item:(TTPhotoPost *)item
{
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:
                                            [item.caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                                            options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                                                              error:nil];

    [cell.descriptionLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
}
```

Any mistakes there? or some way to make att.string faster?

Comment: NSAttributedString with HTML String is time consuming. So maybe by doing it in background, and setting the attributedText once done in main thread (UI things can only be done in main thread) could be more interesting.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730326/nsmutableattributedstring-initwithdata-causing-exc-bad-access-on-rotation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest creating the `NSAttributedString` from HTML once asynchronously, and storing the attributed string in your model. That way you won't have to do the HTML -> attributed string conversion on every cell reuse, which happens a lot when you're scrolling.

Comment: is there any way to strore NSAttributedString in coredata ?

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure. If there isn't, you could store html in CoreData, and parse it into an attributed string as a one time operation

Answer (score 0):

make it asynchronously (I think the issue is connected that scroll view is using main thread as well):

```
- (void)setSubtitleForCell:(TTTableViewCell *)cell item:(TTPhotoPost *)item
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:
                                                [item.caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                                                options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                                                     documentAttributes:nil
                                                                                  error:nil];
        dispatch_on_main_queue(^{
            [cell.descriptionLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
        });
    });
}
```