# Screen freezes while scrolling UITableView

Tags: nsattributedstring, smooth-scrolling, uitableview

Screen freezes while scrolling UITableView if I am using attributedText for showing HTML text in a label inside UITableViewCell.

`titleLbl.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                           options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes: nil error: &err];`

Can someone guide some best ways to do this...

I tried this link, but no help
[NSAttributedString freeze UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299342/nsattributedstring-freeze-uitableview).

Comment: Try to remove HTML text from UITableViewCell or attributed text too.
Just make a Simple UILabel it will resolve you problem.

Comment: try my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663136/1207684